# error in Script. fetching data from json

Tags: jquery, json

i am getting the below error in my script. Please help:

```
missing : after property id
[Break On This Error]   

data.modules[2].fields[0].name:"required";
```

PFB the script:

```
$("#frm").validate({
    "rules": {
        data.modules[2].fields[0].name: "required";
        data.modules[2].fields[1].name: {
            "required": "true",
            data.modules[2].fields[1].name: "true"
        }

        "messages": {
            data.modules[2].fields[0].name: "Enter your firstname",
            data.modules[2].fields[1].name: {
                "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
                "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        }
    });
```

this is my html form:

```
html += '<form id="frm" method="get" type='+data.modules[2].type+' class='+data.modules[2].attributes.class+'name='+data.modules[2].name+
                    'action='+data.modules[2].action+'><p>'+data.modules[2].title+'</p>'
                    html += '<label class="firstname">'+data.modules[2].fields[0].label+'</label>';
                    html += '<input type='+data.modules[2].fields[0].type+'name='+data.modules[2].fields[0].name+'value='
                    +data.modules[2].fields[0].value+'/>';
                    html += '<label class="Email">'+data.modules[2].fields[1].label+'</label>';
                    html += '<input type='+data.modules[2].fields[1].type+'name='+data.modules[2].fields[1].name+'value='
                    +data.modules[2].fields[1].value+'/>';
```

i am getting correct values in above html.have tested by giving alerts.

Comment: You should post the code, not the errors.

Comment: post sample of form html that shows a couple of your inputs. Plugin uses `input` name property for rules and messages objects and they must comply with javascript object notation

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `data.modules[2].fields[0].name` as an identifier in an object literal. The identifier is always a name, never the value of an expression.

If you want to use a value as identifier, you have to create the object first, then set the property using indexing syntax. Example:

```
var obj = {};
obj[data.modules[2].fields[1].name] = "required";
```

(I tried to write the actual code for the object that you are trying to create, but the code is so broken (i.e. wrong or missing separators, unmatched brackets) that's it's impossible to tell what the object structure should be without knowledge about what it's supposed to do.)

Comment: Wouldnt this be complicated then. I am provided the JSON already. So any simpler way to validate form in my script?? please help.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit complicated because you want to use values for the identifiers in the object. There is no good way to create an object like that in a single statement, so you have to build it up from pieces. You *could* use a templating approach by using a string format of the object, replace in the identifiers, and then use `eval` to parse it into an object, but that's pretty much as complicated even if it can be done with a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include commas between the elements of JavaScript dictionaries:

```
$("#frm").validate({
    "rules": {
        data.modules[2].fields[0].name: "required",
        data.modules[2].fields[1].name: {
            "required": "true",
            data.modules[2].fields[1].name: "true"
        },

        "messages": {
            data.modules[2].fields[0].name: "Enter your firstname",
            data.modules[2].fields[1].name: {
                "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
                "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are correct about the commas, but it's the values like `data.modules[2].fields[0].name` used as identifiers that is the cause of the error. The script parser doesn't get as far as the first needed comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables as the keys with the object literal syntax. You can achieve what you want by building the configuration object programatically:

```
var field1 = data.modules[2].fields[0].name;
var field2 = data.modules[2].fields[1].name;

var rules = {};

rules[field1] = "required";
rules[field2] = {
  "required": true
};

var messages = {};

messages[field1] = "Enter your firstname";
messages[field2] = {
  "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
  "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
};

$("#frm").validation({"rules": rules, "messages": messages});
```

Also, your code was missing a closing brace. I'm assuming by your indentation that you want `rules` and `messages` to be on the same level, instead of `messages` being inside of `rules`.

Comment: Tried ur solution. still im getting missing : error on first line itself:

Comment: $("#frm").validation({ 
                    var field1 = data.modules[2].fields[0].name;
     var field2 = data.modules[2].fields[1].name;

     var rules = {};

     rules[field1] = "required";
     rules[field2] = {
         "required": true
     };

     var messages = {};
     messages[field1] = "Enter your firstname";
     messages[field2] = {
         "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
         "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
     };
     });

Comment: i am using jquery.validation.js

Comment: You should try it outside of the `validation` call. Substitute the code you've posted by this one.

Comment: Hi Thats working now. But how will i validate this on click of submit button. i need to write this inside a function and then do click event right? but that 's not wrking.